# Checking if an instance of a specific class exists in a list

Tags: java, class, linked-list, variable-assignment, instanceof

Okay, apologies if this is answered already. I tried looking, but I didn't find an answer.

Now, I have a linked list utility class (linked in one direction) which contains various all purpose utility methods for different things. What I'm trying to do is make a method which is capable of taking as parametre an instance of any given class, then proceeds to check if an instance of such class exists in the list, returning true if it does, and false if it doesn't. The list itself contains instances of several different classes.

The method would be used in conjunction with a list detailing the contents of a space on a game board: If the space contains an enemy, show the icon of the enemy and make the space impassable, if it contains an item, show the icon of the item and so on and so forth. The real kicker here is that the method should be able to deal with any and all classes, so I cannot use something like:

if(foo instanceof Enemy)
{
.
.
.
}

Here's what I initially tried to do:
    //this method is inside a LinkedList class

```
public boolean exists(Object o)
{
    int i = 0;
    boolean output = false;
    //koko() returns the size of the linked list
    while(i < koko() && !output)
    {
        //alkio(i) returns an Object type reference to the entity in index i
        if(alkio(i) instanceof o.getClass())
        {
            output = true;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

But it resulted in this:https://www.dropbox.com/s/5mjr45uymxotzlq/Screenshot%202016-04-06%2001.16.59.png?dl=0

Yes, this is a homework (or rather, a part of big homework) but the teacher won't answer at two AM and my google-fu is too weak.

halp plz

- Nar

Comment: Why would you be taking as input an object instead of a `Class` specifically?

Comment: How do I take a class as a parametre? That would be easiest but I wasn't fully aware this was possible... what's the syntax?

Comment: What do you think o.getClass returns? It returns a `Class`. Or you can write the literal `MyClass.class`.

Comment: So how do you actually put that into the method header...?

public boolean exists(//what goes here?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamic way to do `instanceof` is to use the [`Class.isInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29) method:

> Determines if the specified `Object` is assignment-compatible with the object represented by this `Class`. This method is the dynamic equivalent of the Java language `instanceof` operator.

So, `alkio(i) instanceof o.getClass()` should be written `o.getClass().isInstance(alkio(i))`.

Comment: and just to make sure: If parametre given to the method is of type Foo, and the reference returned by alkio(i) points to an instance of, say... Object-class, the method you told me about there would return false?

Comment: And conversely, if the entity at index i would be of Foo-type, it would return true?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Integer myInt = 1;
    System.out.println(exists(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3), myInt)); //true
    System.out.println(exists(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"), myInt)); //false

}

/**
 * Returns whether an object exists in @list that is an instance of the class of object @o.
 */
public static boolean exists(List<?> list, Object o)
{
    return list == null || o == null ? false : list.stream().filter(o.getClass()::isInstance).findAny().isPresent();
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot understand this... what are you going for here?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then you need to pass the class to your method, not an instance of the class:

```
public boolean exists (Class checkClass) {
    ...
    if (item.getClass().equals(checkClass)) {
        return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

You then call this as:

```
if (myList.exists(Enemy.class)) {
    ...
}
```

However you should consider a different model as this shows some fairly poor object oriented design. A better approach would be to have an `interface` representing all things that can go on your map. Something like:

```
public enum MapObjectType {
    ENEMY, ALLY, WALL;
}

public interface MapObject {
    MapObjectType getType();
}
```

Then each of your classes that can be placed into the list representing your map should implement this interface. For example:

```
public class Enemy implements MapObject {

    @Override
    public MapObjectType getType() {
        return MapObjectType.ENEMY;
    }
}
```

Then your method could be a more sensible:

```
public boolean hasObjectOfType(MapObjectType type) {
    ...
    if (item.getType().equals(type)) {
        return true;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This sounds very neat... so if I understand correctly, the enum contains all the things that go into the map, and interface... what about the interface? Does the linked list implement that interface? Does the interface MapObject contain only the method mentioned above?

Comment: @Narmondur the enum represents the types of objects that go into the map. Each class of object should then implement the interface. I'll add an example to the answer.

Comment: I solved this with the Class.isInstance()-method, mainly because I suspect the teacher would frown slightly at the use of enums, as we haven't gone through those (only reason I know about them is I happened to stumble on a course far above my skill level once and they mentioned it). On top of that, using a method that is specifically made by me for a different class would defeat the all-purpose nature this particular implementation of a linked list should have.

Regardless, I'm going to save this page somewhere cause your reply gave me valuable information  I'll use in the future

Thank you :)